# Display math formulas without webview

Tags: android, latex

I am writing Android app, where I need a lot of math formulas. I searched how to display math formulas on Android, but all possibilities I found uses extension of webView which is to slow for me. (Formulas are displayed in recyclerView and with webviews, scroling was anything but smooth).

So I end up with solution, where I export formulas from latex as pictures and displaying them, but this solution is not optimal. Is there a way to display math formulas without using webview or without exporting formulas as pictures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am listing some of the pretty cool libraries for showing formula at text view.

- https://github.com/gregcockroft/AndroidMath
- https://github.com/Nishant-Pathak/MathView
- https://github.com/frhnfrq/MathView

I hope it can work for you.

Comment: All of the above-mentioned libraries use web view.